# How to focus on last activated program?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms, focus

If you are making windows form application and you have "Notepad" and "web browser" open ,How to Give Focus to the last one that had focus before your application got the focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressing Alt+Tab always gets you back to the previously active window.  It is a one-liner in code:

```
    SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}")
```

Comment: It's good to note that this will work with WPF if you include System.Windows.Forms in the references.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callbackfunction along with a collection of APIs to find the list of programs (open windows) which can be seen by Alt-Tab(without viewing Alt-Tab window).

First declare the collection of APIs to be used:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int uCmd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int EnumWindows(CallBackPtr callPtr, int lPar);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder         lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wparam, int lparam);

const int WM_GETTEXT = 0xD;

private static int windowCount = 0;
```

Then you need to enumerate through windows and activate the last one:

```
public static bool EnumWindowProc(int hwnd, int lParam)
{
    if (!IsWindowVisible((IntPtr)hwnd) || GetWindow((IntPtr)hwnd, GW_OWNER) != IntPtr.Zero)
    return true;

    string name = GetWindowTextRaw((IntPtr)hwnd);
    if (name.Length > 0)
    {
        windowCount++;
        if (windowCount == 2) //The previouse active window
        {
            SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)hwnd);
            return false;
        }
    }


    return true;
}
```

And use the following code to retrieve the name of the window.

```
public static string GetWindowTextRaw(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    var length = (int)SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
    var sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, sb.Capacity, sb);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

At the end call the following function:

```
public void ActivateLastWindow()
{
    callBackPtr = EnumWindowProc;
    windowCount = 0;
    EnumWindows(callBackPtr, 0);
}
```

Comment: You can make this a lot simpler by pinvoking GetForegroundWindow() at the start of the program.

Comment: This approach is more general, can be used after the program has been started, by pushing a button on a form, etc.
If the sequence of the running program changed, the GetForegroundWindow which is called at the start of the program is not applicable any more.

Comment: @Thunder-KC inc 
thank you for the fast answer ,I'm new to User32.dll using so I need time to do it with your 'code'.

Comment: @Hans Passant Passant , Does GetForegroundWindow() returns a window from another app?