# How to write a new Alt+Tab task switcher for Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, msdn

I am told, that the program that handles the ALT+TAB input is called task switcher. But I am not happy with the task switcher that is provided from stock.

Could anyone give me a push to the right direction so I get an idea how I could write one on my own and replace the old with the new one?

It's not that I have no programming experiance, I just don't know where to begin on this special one. :D

Thank you!

Comment: TBH, I doubt you'll beat ProcessExplorer from sysinternals, unless this is purely for learning purposes :)

Comment: Well no.. actually I just want to be able to close a selected window. Let's say I press ALT+TAB and can now switch between the tasks. If I press Q ,instead of TAB - still holding the ALT key down, the selected task should be closed. 

Is there any way to accomplish that? ^^

Answer (score 3):

There are three essential ingredients for writing a replacement switcher in Windows (these were tested under Windows 7):

1. Capture Alt+Tab: For this I would use [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and a [low-level keyboard hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`WH_KEYBOARD_LL`).
2. Enumerate the windows you could switch between: Two options for this are [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or the UI Automation Framework (managed code can use [`System.Windows.Automation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
3. Perform the switching: You can use [`SwitchToThisWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`SetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but in either case you will need to set [`uiAccess=true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742884%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your manifest. This will additionally require you to sign your executable and install it in Program Files. You **do not** need to call `AttachThreadInput` or perform other such shenanigans.

For a more thorough discussion, see [this blog post](http://blog.misterfoo.com/2014/02/how-do-i-write-alttab-replacement.html).

Comment: Code from GitHub: https://github.com/misterfoo/taskSwitch2

Answer (score 0):

We have answered your question in this link:
[How to focus on last activated program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659970/how-to-focus-on-last-activated-program/13660585#13660585)
By using this code instead of that one you can have the list of open windows,

```
string name = GetWindowTextRaw((IntPtr)hwnd);
if (name.Length > 0)
{
     windowArray.Add(hwnd);
}
```

Now you can use the following code to switch between windows:

```
SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)windowArray.sth);
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint!

But do you have an idea how to replace the existing task switcher by the new one?

Comment: One way is to use keyboard hook functions.

Comment: Could you explain this a little to me? Actually I dont really want to write a whole new task switcher.. I just want to add a single functionality (closing a selected task). But since the task switcher seems to be a program on its own I will have to write a new one as it seems..

Comment: By searching  "SetWindowsHookEx", "LowLevelKeyboardProc" and "Alt+Tab" in google, u can find sample codes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/226359, http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?600312-LowLevelKeyboardProc-Alt-key ...

Comment: Thank you :) I'll go for it!