# Is it possible to program a custom dialog/pop-up for Alt+Tab switcher for Win 10?

Tags: windows, winapi, alt-tab

I saw this post by Raymond Chen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12865402/257299

The title says it all: Is it possible to program a custom dialog/pop-up for <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> switcher on Win 10?

Example: Can I trap `EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART`, then show my custom <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>  dialog with highest Z-Order?  To be clear, I know this could be a security issue.  Please assume the user local admin access.

Why?  I want to program a replacement for the Win 10 "classic" <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> dialog that allows me to use the arrow keys.  On Win 7,  it was possible to do a key sequence like this: <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> (hold), the dialog would pop-up, then arrow keys would allow you to move left/right/up/down.  After release <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>, the window focus would change.  Very convenient!  For me, the default Win 10 <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> dialog is awful, but the "classic" mode only needs a minor tweak.

Finally, I have Google'd like crazy before I asked this question.  I cannot find anything.

Comment: *"To be clear, I know this could be a security issue."* - I don't see how that would be a security issue. It's not like Windows controls access at the UI level.

Comment: Have you actually tried to code one? There was a powertoy for XP that had a custom alt+tab window so it is possible.

Comment: @Anders Great tip.  I learned more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PowerToys#PowerToys_for_Windows_XP

However, the latest version of PowerToys for Win10 no longer has the "Alt-Tab Replacement Task Switcher".  And there is no source code for the old XP PowerToys.

Good news: I found a similar question with lots of other great links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668935/how-to-write-a-new-alttab-task-switcher-for-windows

Comment: As far as I know, specifically EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART does not really work in Windows10. Since you want to do a task switcher replacement I guess you don't really need to listen to that event. But if you still want to capture Alt+Tab, with the win32 api, I guess you can take a look at my solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49597746/511801